# mysql: please help me get rid of nested clauses

Tags: mysql

I have written the following query (the repeated parts put together from string constants) that tries to do the following in a shared calendar app.

- search `status_relation` for all users with status not equal to 0 at current date+time
- search `default_status_relation` for all users with status not equal to 0 at current weekday+time.  This gives default weekly statuses when nothing is available in `status_relation`.
- full outer join the two
- then join on usernames from userid
- this then gets processed by php which will display either the status (or default status, if status doesn't exist) of all users on that day who have status!=0.
- the php needs to know whether it was returned a status or default status

Currently the query works (with a UNION to simulate an outer join).  However, I would like to optimize it - I understand removing the subqueries might help.  How can that be done?

```
SELECT q.*,
   users.username,
   users.userid AS uid
FROM   (SELECT *
    FROM   ((SELECT sr.status   AS srstatus,
                    dsr.status  AS dsrstatus,
                    sr.userid   AS sruserid,
                    dsr.userid  AS dsruserid
             FROM   (SELECT *
                     FROM   status_relation
                     WHERE  DATE = '2012-03-19'
                            AND TIME = '0'
                    ) sr
             LEFT JOIN 
                    (SELECT *
                     FROM   default_status_relation
                     WHERE  weekday = '0'
                     AND TIME = '0') 
                    ) dsr
             ON sr.userid = dsr.userid)
          UNION
            (SELECT sr.status   AS srstatus,
                    dsr.status  AS dsrstatus,
                    sr.userid   AS sruserid,
                    dsr.userid  AS dsruserid
             FROM   (SELECT *
                     FROM   status_relation
                     WHERE  DATE = '2012-03-19'
                            AND TIME = '0') sr
                    RIGHT JOIN (SELECT *
                                FROM   default_status_relation
                                WHERE  weekday = '0'
                                       AND TIME = '0') dsr
                      ON sr.userid = dsr.userid)
       ) myjoin
    WHERE  ( ( sruserid IS NOT NULL
               AND srstatus != '0' )
              OR ( sruserid IS NULL
                   AND dsrstatus != '0' ) )) q
   LEFT JOIN users
     ON ( q.sruserid = users.userid
           OR q.dsruserid = users.userid )
```

Comment: Generally speaking, unless you are using some sort of aggregation function like SUM(), subqueries are not needed. This looks pretty complex though :-/ Why are you using RIGHT JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN?

Comment: I'm trying to do a full outer join (which mysql 5.1 doesn't support afaik) by unioning a left and right join of the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to replace this part :

```
(SELECT sr.status   AS srstatus,
    dsr.status  AS dsrstatus,
    sr.userid   AS sruserid,
    dsr.userid  AS dsruserid
 FROM   (SELECT *
         FROM   status_relation
         WHERE  DATE = '2012-03-19'
             AND TIME = '0'
        ) sr
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT *
    FROM   default_status_relation
    WHERE  weekday = '0'
        AND TIME = '0') 
    ) dsr
ON sr.userid = dsr.userid)
```

by

```
SELECT sr.status   AS srstatus,
    dsr.status  AS dsrstatus,
    sr.userid   AS sruserid,
    dsr.userid  AS dsruserid
 FROM status_relation sr
 left join default_status_relation dsr
   ON sr.userid = dsr.userid and 
       sr.date = '2012-03-19' and 
       sr.time = TIME = '0' and
       dsr.weekday = 0 and 
       dsr.time = 0;
```

You can do the same on the UNION

Comment: I thought so too, but then - oddly enough - the query then returns rows where the date is not null and does not match the given date (likewise for time).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean here... Which date is not OK? Maybe you can add a " and dsr.date is not null"?